# How do I download pictures from my phone?

Tags: drivers

I have a htc hero 4g and want to download pictures.  The software does not recognize the phone and I don't know how to find the drivers.

Comment: When you connected with the PC,did you turn on USB storage?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Android app [WebSharing Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.websharing&hl=en) for copying files on your phone to your desktop and vice versa. Your phone should be connected to a wireless network and the desktop from which you would like to access the phone filesystem should be in the same network.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered online alternatives? Ubuntu One offers *5GB of free storage*, and paired with the app for your phone you could easily transfer the pictures back and forth.

Another option would be to look in the Ubuntu Software Center, if my memory serves me right theres one or two applications for connecting to phones (though one is for CDMA [or non sim card] phones so I don't know if that will help.